# API Gateway CORS error even though data returned

Tags: javascript, aws-api-gateway

I've created a test API in API gateway with CORS enabled already

[image]

But when I call my API using the generated SDK,

```
api.ec2Get()
  .then(function (data) {
    console.log(data)
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.error(err)
  })
```

It fails with

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://hbegoa3re6.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/awsmanagement_staging/ec2. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

But when I check in my network tab, its actually OK

[image]

Data is actually returned

[image]

Whats wrong?

Comment: Maybe you need to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin to response header.

Comment: @李骏骁 you are right! You can create this as an answer so I can mark it answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin to response header.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Proxy Resources? If so you need to set the response headers by code.

If you arent using proxy, you can just click on action -> Enable cors